# Why do some keys, once converted to strings, not convert back to their original keycodes?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to take a keypress, convert it to a string, then convert the string back to its original keypress int value.

Assume I have this:

```
KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();

string keyChar = kc.ConvertToString((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)e.KeyCode);
int key = (int)e.KeyCode;

Debug.WriteLine( e.KeyCode + " " + (int)e.KeyCode);

Key tempkey;
Enum.TryParse(keyChar, out tempkey );

Debug.WriteLine( tempkey + " " + (int)tempkey );
```

Everything seems to work fine. For instance:

Test case: `F5`

Output: 
`F5 116`
`F5 116`

Test case: ` (Oemtilde)

Output: `Oemtilde 192`
`Oemtilde 192`

Test case: `X`

Output:
`X 88`
`X 88`

Seems to be fine...

Then I do this:

Test case: `1`

Output: `D1 49`
`Lbutton 1`

Why is it that some keys don't convert back to their original values?

Noteable keys it hasn't worked with:

1,2,3,...,9,0, Insert, Delete, Page Down, Page Up

Edit:

Test case: `1` (on the keypad on the right side of keyboard)

Output: `NumPad1 97` `NumPad1 97`

Comment: Are teh keys that are giving you trouble all on the keypad?

Comment: Only the ones I've listed (1,2,3,...,9,0, Insert, Delete, Page Down, Page Up) are the ones giving me a problem. The keypad on the right side of the keyboard doesn't give an issue. Even the `*`, `/` signs are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a fundamental error. `KeysConverter` converts the key to a string, so `Keys.D1` (which is the code for the `1` key on the top row) converts to the string "1", as that's what the key represents. `Enum.TryParse` tries to make sense of this, but there is no `Keys.1` tag (obviously) so it simply converts the string as the numeric value "1". `(Keys) 1` is indeed `Keys.LButton`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this roundtrip conversion, so I wouldn't know how to correct your code, but that explains what you're seeing.

Comment: Given an e.KeyCode for the button `1`, how would you convert it to its `int` value, then to its string name, and then convert that string back to its `int` value?

Comment: @John: you could do that by switching on the value -- `Keys.D0` through `Keys.D9` are neatly in order. But that conversion doesn't seem necessary in the first place, because, if you want the keycode `49` as a `Keys` instance, you can simply do `(Keys) 49`, or, in the code of your question, `(Keys) e.KeyCode`. And if you want a string that unambiguously represents the keycode, just convert the numeric value -- `e.KeyCode.ToString()`.

Comment: Ahhhh. The `e.KeyCode.ToString()` just helped me out a bunch. Much is appreciated. Thank you.